# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, изображения

Появилась проблема с ошибкой:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Хотя библиотеку я подключил. Ошибка возникает возможно потому, что путь некорректный, но когда я его вывожу, выводит:

> b'C:\Users\\Desktop\Programming\AppleGame\KODGAME\dom.jpg'.

В чем может быть проблема?
Вот часть моего кода, в котором возникает ошибка:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from PIL.Image import core as image 
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
def encode(kod):
    uni_code = easygui.fileopenbox()
    global img_path 
    img_path = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',uni_code).encode('ascii','ignore')
    n = 0
    print(img_path)
    image = cv.imread(img_path)
    height = image.shape[0] // ошибка
    width = image.shape[1] 
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            if (len(kod)>n):
                a = image[i,j,0]
                b = image[i,j,1]
                c = image[i,j,2]
                image[i][j] = [a,b,c+ord(kod[n])-96]
                n = n + 1
    cv.imwrite('withkode.bmp',image)
```

Comment: Написав `.encode('ascii','ignore')` вы явно выбросили из пути своё русское имя пользователя

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, `Пользователь` вернулся, но ошибка не исчезла.

Comment: Возможно, с этим путём всё же нужно как-то дальше воевать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В переменной img_path должен быть полный путь до файла